# Initialization and lambda-type argument

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, lambda, initialization

I have such a utility class:

```
struct Atreturn
{
    std::function<void()> funcdestr;
    Atreturn( std::function<void()> fd ): funcdestr(fd) {}
    ~Atreturn() { funcdestr(); }
};
```

Note no `explicit` attribute at constructor.

Possible use should be:

1. **Direct-initializing constructor call:**

   ```
   Atreturn hook ( [something]() { DestroySomething(something); } );
   ```
2. **Copy-initializing constructor call:**

   ```
   Atreturn hook = [something]() { DestroySomething(something); };
   ```
3. **Direct-list-initializing constructor call:**

   ```
   Atreturn hook { [something]() { DestroySomething(something); }};
   ```

Now the question: to my best knowledge, the method #1 and #2 should be allowed as they are theoretically the same thing, provided that there's no `explicit` at the constructor, while #3 should not be allowed because this syntax prevents conversions (at least it's so for `int` if you tried `int{2.1}`).

However, gcc 4.9 allows method #1 and #3, but not #2 (and says `conversion from '...::<lambda()>' to non-scalar 'Atreturn' type requested`). This sounds crazy because it normally happens only if you have `explicit` constructor. Can anybody explain, why?

Additionally, let me make this problem more explicit: I need some not too clumsy syntax to initialize this Atreturn object, at least without the need of extra braces or parentheses. The problem is that editors with auto-indent function have problems with proper reindentation when the argument is C++11 lambda. So I need some syntax that could be expressed as:

```
 Atreturn BLAH BLAH BLAH [something]() { DestroySomething(something); };
```

Comment: (Also add the copy-list-initializing construction: `Areturn hook = { ... }`?)

Comment: That's the same as method #3, this = is optional in C++11.

Comment: #1 and #2 are *not* the same. They would be if the type on the right was `Atreturn`, but it's not.

Comment: Yes, the `=` is optional, but *direct-list-initialisation* (without the `=`) and *copy-list-initialisation* (with the `=`) are not the same.

Comment: Please focus on the question. Actually they are somehow both allowed, which isn't a problem for me. My problem is that method #2 is rejected.

Comment: _"Please focus on the question_" They **are** focusing on the question, by pointing out your fundamental misunderstandings of the syntaxes you're asking about.

Comment: I'm pleased to get this explained - but this doesn't make me closer to the solution. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> while #3 should not be allowed because this syntax prevents conversions (at least it's so for int if you tried int{2.1}).

That's not quite right. The rule is that *narrowing conversions* are not allowed. Other types of conversions are allowed. `int{2.1}` is a narrowing conversion, because it modifies the value, losing precision. `int{2.0}` is not a narrowing conversion, because the value is not changed.

The reason #2 fails is that it requires two implicit user-defined conversions, which is forbidden.

Conceptually, a copy-initialization such as:

```
Atreturn hook = []() {};
```

is equivalent to:

```
Atreturn hook = Atreturn([]() {});
```

(except that it cannot call 'explicit' constructors, and the compiler is allowed to elide the copy).

This means that first the lambda would have to implicitly convert to `function<void()>` and then that would have to implicitly convert to `Atreturn`. Both those conversions are a "user-defined conversion sequence" meaning they call a constructor, rather than built-in conversions like `int` to `long`, and the standard says that an implicit conversion sequence cannot include more than one user-defined conversion.

The problem is actually unrelated to lambdas, you can demonstrate exactly the same error like this:

```
struct L { };
struct F { F(L) { } };
struct A { A(F) { } };
A a = L();

l.cc:4:9: error: conversion from ‘L’ to non-scalar type ‘A’ requested
 A a = L();
         ^
```

Again, the problem is that the implicit conversion sequence `L -> F -> A` involves two user-defined conversions, which is forbidden.

I don't have much sympathy for your problem of wanting to adapt the code to help auto-indentation -- the code should not be mangled to suit a flawed editor. However, another option would be to add a template constructor which accepts anything that can be converted to `std::function<void()>` e.g.

```
struct Atreturn
{
  using func_type = std::function<void()>;
  template<typename T,
           typename Requires = decltype(func_type(std::declval<T&&>())>
    Atreturn(T t) : funcdestr(std::move(t)) { }
  ...
};
```

This will allow the lambda to be converted directly to `Atreturn`, without requiring an implicit conversion to `function<void()>` first.

Comment: Lambda to `function<void()>` is quite ok, but where do you see the need to convert that to `Atreturn`? Shouldn't the initialization with the equal sign use the 1-argument constructor with parameter of that type?

Comment: @Ethouris No, direct-initialisation (no `=`) and copy-initialisation (with `=`) are *not* the same. The latter one requires creating a temporary and using it as the argument for the copy ctor (even if that's elided in practice).

Comment: @Ethouris, I've updated the answer to explain that. On the right-hand side of the `=` the language rules say there is a temporary `Atreturn` object. Even if that temporary gets elided away, the rules about overloading and conversions must behave as if the temporary was created.

Comment: @JonathanWakely regarding your last edit: wouldn't it be better to make it `Atreturn(T&& t) : funcdestr(std::forward<T>(t))`?

Comment: @AntonSavin, there's no difference in the generated code, and I was recently persuaded that copying by value should be preferred when consuming the object directly (e.g. copying it into a member variable here), whereas a forwarding reference should be preferred when simply forwarding on to some other function. That's how `std::function` does it too.